# Tocar son utilizando html e javascript com um array de arquivo de áudios

Tags: javascript

Quero criar um projeto para fazer um tipo de jogo para eu estudar música. Tocaria um acorde e eu responderia que nota seria. O sistema me daria a resposta se acertei ou não. Isso é para treinar meu ouvido. Assim, estou começando com os primeiros passos, mas não consigo apontar para um nome do arquivo no array.

- `index.html`:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>    
  <html>    
  <head>    
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">    
  <title>    
  OUVIDO ABSOLUTO    
  </title>    
  <script src='/scripts/sons.js'></script>    
  </head>    
  <body>    

  <br><br>    

  <audio id="audio"></audio>    

  <form>    
  <label form="tocar">    
  <input type="button" value="tocar" onclick="tocar()">    
  </label>    
  </form>    
  </body>    
  </html>
```

- `scripts/sons.js`:

```js
  lista_acordes=["C.wav", "D.wav", "E.wav"];     

  function tocar() {    
  var son = document.getElementById("audio");     
  son.src=lista_acordes[1];     
  son.play();     
  }
```

Comment: Não creio que a pergunta seja duplicata, nem mesmo se pareçam. Uma pergunta é sobre **como chamar um arquivo externo**, e esta é **como atribuir um valor a um atributo Html por Javascript**.

Comment: @LeAndrade Tem razão. Eu li as duas e me pareceram iguais. Já reabri. ;)

Comment: Sem problemas @Sam :) a comunidade é sempre para ajudar, vamo que vamo!

Comment: André me parece que faltou apenas você setar um **src** na tag `audio`, pois quando faz no Javascript **`son.src=lista_acordes[1];`** son que é o nome da variável para  a tag audio ainda não tem o atributo src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom André, não entendi muito bem como será o fluxo de tocar o áudio ao clicar no botão, mas se quer atribuir um **src** a tag `audio` através de um array Javascript, você apenas faltou colocar o atributo vazio no html:

```js
lista_acordes = ["C.wav", "D.wav", "E.wav"];

function tocar() {
  var som = document.getElementById("audio");
  som.src = lista_acordes[1];
  som.play();
  console.log(som);
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" src=""></audio>

<form>
  <label form="tocar">    
  <input type="button" value="tocar" onclick="tocar()">    
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: o fluxo de tocar será definido da seguinte forma: uma função que vou criar vai retornar um número aleatório entre 0 e o tamanho do array-1. Haverão mais funções para validar se acertou ou errou e qual o nome da nota tocada. Só lembrando que estou fazendo uma espécie de joguinho de música para treinar o ouvido. Vou fazendo e testando e quando trava em algum ponto, sendo assim, postei duas perguntas sobre o mesmo projeto.